# combine matrix and list in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a list and matrix like this:

```
list = [(a1, b1), (a2, b2), (a3, b3)]

matrix = [1 1 1
          0 0 0
          1 0 1]
```

the combination output must be:

```
result = [(a1, b1) 1 1 1
          (a2, b2) 0 0 0
          (a3, b3) 1 0 1]
```

How can I do this elegantly (with no loop)?

Comment: @Novak ‘s answer would probably work but there is a reason that loops exist. Unless you were playing code golf I don’t see a reason you shouldn’t use loops.

Comment: Python doesn't have a built-in matrix type. Your `matrix = [...]` line is currently not valid Python. Can you update the examples with actual Python code?

Comment: @GoldmanLee  Avoiding loops is not necessary, but i want to make my code as fast as I can. Because it is competition in my class on the run time

Comment: @HannesOvrén I know, It isn't the code, just an simple ex

Comment: So you want SO to win a class competition for you? Then you are at the wrong place.

Comment: @b-fg It is a very big program. I do my homework by my self and ask here for a little trick!!!

Comment: @Aprilis It's impossible to give advice when we have no idea what data structures you are using, because the answer will depend on that.

Comment: @Aprilis, using complex functions from external modules such as panda will make the program slower. The panda function most likely uses loops anyways, it just hides it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

matrix = pd.DataFrame(matrix)

matrix.insert(loc=0, column='new_col', value=new_col)
```